# Navigator vs NavigatorIOS React Native application

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, react-native

I have a React Native app working using NavigatorIOS API, and am trying to translate the same code to use Navigator API. My trouble is when creating a NavigatorIOS component, the navigator is implicitly passed, whereas in Navigator, you must call renderScene and make your own navigator prop. I'm not sure what navigator to pass (do i create one or what?).

The structure of the app is that there are 2 tabs: Book and Search, and BookList is another component which lists all the book entries, so that when you press one of them, it brings you to BookDetail. Right now, pressing a book brings me to the same page (BookList). I think this is because there's only one page in the route, but I'm not sure how to initialize the route and navigator.

This is where I call the navigator to push a scene onto the route in BookList:

```
showBookDetail(book) {
   this.props.navigator.push({
       title: book.volumeInfo.title,
       component: BookDetail,
       passProps: {book}
   });
}
```

This is the NavigatorIOS version:

```
class Books extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
    <NavigatorIOS
            style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{
        title: 'Featured Books',
        component: BookList
        }}/>
    );
}
```

This is my Navigator version that is not working:

```
class Books extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Navigator
            style={styles.container}
            initialRoute={{ title: 'Featured Books', index: 0}}
            renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
                <BookList title={route.title} navigator={navigator}/>
            }
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the body of your `renderScene` function returns the `<BookList>` component, so it's not really surprising that when it is called you just see another BookList. Try something like this instead:

```
renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
    <route.component title={route.title} navigator={navigator}/>     
}
```

As long as you have imported or required BookDetail in the source file for Books, renderScene will be passed the `route` object you specified in `navigator.push`, which has the component property `BookDetail`

Note that you will also have to change your `initialRoute` to have a `component` property set to `BookList` if you take this approach